# Mobile and web app and single meteor project

Tags: django, mobile, meteor

I am thinking what technology should I use for my next project.
There will be web application and mobile app (not only RWD version of web app).
Mobile and web should may sync with each other.

Is it possible to run both from single meteor code base?
Maybe should I drop meteor and use, for example, django as the backend and ionic as mobile client?

Comment: Meteor does support [Cordova](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/mobileconfigjs). As for what to use, you should probably go for whatever you have the most fun with.

Answer (score 0):

Django vs Meteor is a big question in and of itself, and is primarily opinion based.

Meteor supports Cordova/Phonegap and you can use ionic with meteor. There's a package called meteoric, and there's an angularjs meteor ionic integration too.

You can use the same codebase for your mobile and web app. It's probably a good idea to put your mobile specific code in its own package, so that it isn't loaded every time someone visits your website. Others have created a totally new project for their mobile apps which contains client only code and shares the same backend as the web app. You need to make sure updates work properly if you take this approach and there are packages that help you with this.